# For calculating chance to hit, does imprecision of the shooter matter if it's less than the uncertainty of position of the target?

Tags: probability

## Context:

I'm trying to estimate how well defenders can shoot things down for myself and other science fiction authors, and how the quality of one's aim or target tracking affects things as much as not knowing where the target is. This came up because attempting to write combat in space realistically reduces down to how well a weapon can aim very precisely and slew with low jitter, how well missiles can randomly dodge while flying in, how good sensors are, and how good the attacker's electronic warfare is.

However, all of this is going to distract from an *abstract notion of hit chance*. However, since stackexchange wants thorough context, I am giving it.

**I am asking about hit chance so I can model what I am setting out to do numerically.** I've already started building a simple program to do this, but I don't know the right way to roll my hit chances if I have both a lack of precise aim and a lack of precise target data, nor do I know if I can take any shortcuts if one is vastly bigger than the other, which is important given how many iterations this takes over a multi-light-second approach at realistic velocities, which is on the order of tens to low hundreds of kilometers per second.

To this end I've researched angular resolution of sensors, seen current levels of jitter with aim and active tracking, and done thought experiments to figure out engagement distances. I've also worked out and referenced existing moving targets of various sizes and speeds. Where I reached the limit of my ability to self teach is modeling probability in this context.

## The Problem:

The problem, put as pedantically as I can, is as follows:

**I need a formula or equation or integral or *something* that has parameters for both angular imprecision of the shooter, and angular imprecision of the target's location, so that I can numerically simulate shooting an incoming target.**

Put another way, **if I know how many seconds of arc or nano-radians of imprecision I have for aim, and the location of a target, how do I model my chance to hit a target of finite size?**

I asked here because I'm writing a program and want to how to program the chance to hit something.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144927/discussion-on-question-by-cthon-for-calculating-chance-to-hit-does-imprecision); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll study a simplier one dimensional problem because the additional dimension does not essentially change the analysis (and one dimension is involved enough).

**A jittery shot at an unpredictable target:**

Consider a target which is a line of length $2 w$. At the moment the shot is taken, this target is at a position $x$ which is a Gaussian random variable with distribution
$$ p_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_x^2}}e^{-x^2/2\sigma_x^2}.$$

Now consider a shot fired from some distance $\ell$ away from the target. Consider that this shot was aimed at $x=0$, but it deviates by an angle $\theta$ from its intended direction due to error or environmental effects. Consider that this angle is also a Gaussian random variable with distribution
$$ p_\Theta(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_\theta^2}}e^{-\theta^2/2\sigma_\theta^2}.$$
The bullet will then end up at $x' = \theta \ell, $ even though it was intended to end up at $x'=0$. The probability that the target is hit is then
$$ P_{hit} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty I(-w + x \leq \ell \theta \leq x + w)p_X(x)p_\Theta(\theta) d\theta dx,$$
where $I(x)$ is $1$ if its argument returns True and is otherwise $0$. We have
\begin{align} P_{hit} &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \hspace{4pt} p_X(x)\int_{(-w+x)/\ell}^{(w+x)/\ell} d\theta \hspace{4pt} p_\Theta(\theta)
\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \hspace{4pt} p_X(x) \Big[ \text{erf}\Big(\frac{x+w}{2\ell \sigma_\theta}\Big) - \text{erf}\Big(\frac{x-w}{2\ell \sigma_\theta}\Big)\Big].\end{align}

**The case of a strongly jittery shot:**

It is challenging to proceed analytically, but if we consider that the distance to the target is very large, so that jitter can easily cause us to miss, we can Taylor expand the error functions as
$$ \frac{1}{2}\Big[\text{erf}\Big(\frac{x+w}{2\ell \sigma_\theta}\Big) - \text{erf}\Big(\frac{x-w}{2\ell \sigma_\theta}\Big)\Big] \approx \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{w}{2\ell \sigma_\theta}e^{-x^2/4\ell^2\sigma_\theta^2},$$
giving
$$ P_{hit} = \frac{w}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_x\sigma_\theta \ell}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\Big[-\frac{x^2}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{2\ell^2\sigma_\theta^2 } + \frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}\Big)\Big] = \frac{w \bar{\sigma} }{\sigma_x\sigma_\theta \ell},$$
where $\frac{1}{\bar{\sigma}^2} = \frac{1}{2\ell^2\sigma_\theta^2 } + \frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}$.
Writing this out further we have
$$P_{hit} = \frac{w}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_x^2}{2} + \ell^2\sigma_\theta^2 }}. $$
Here we can see the hitting probability increases with the target size, decreases with the distance to the target, decreases with the jitter in the shot, and decreases with the typical size of target movements.

**The case of weak uncertainty of position of the target:**

When the position of the target is quite certain, we can approximate the integral involving error functions in this $\ell \sigma_\theta \ll \sigma_x$ limit. Taylor expanding the difference of error functions when $x/(2\ell\sigma_\theta)\ll 1$ and integrating provides
$$ P_{hit} \approx \text{erf}\Big(\frac{w}{2\ell\sigma_\theta}\Big). $$
The error function satisfies $\text{erf}(0)=0$ and $\text{erf}(\infty)\rightarrow 1$. This means when the target gets big ($w\rightarrow \infty$) or the jitter gets small ($\sigma\rightarrow 0$), hitting is guaranteed. Likewise when the shooter gets very far away, $l \rightarrow \infty$, hitting is unlikely. Notably, the result is independent of the amount of uncertainty in the position of the target, as characterized by $\sigma_x$.

**The answer to the question in the title:**

Now, to the question in your title - "Does imprecision of the shooter matter if it's less than the uncertainty in position of the target?"
To address this, we consider the case of a strongly jittery shot, i.e. one where the jitter is strong enough to easily lead to missing the target.Expanding this result for $\sigma_x \rightarrow 0$ provides
$$ P_{hit} = \frac{w}{\ell \sigma_\theta}\Big(1 - \frac{\sigma_x^2}{4\ell^2\sigma_\theta^2}\Big).$$
Here the result is only weakly dependent on uncertainty in the target position.